# Error code 1 when trying to install railway cli

Tags: node.js, railway

I am trying to install railway cli using their documentation and I keep getting Error code 1. I've had no issues with any other packages. The documentation says I need node version 16.X to run the command and I have verified I am running version 16.15.0. I am rather rusty with this stuff since I finished college for web dev 5 years ago and haven't really done much since. Trying some online courses through Udemy to refresh. This is what my terminal is saying

```
$ npm i -g @railway/cli
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./npm-install/postinstall.js
npm ERR! https://github.com/railwayapp/cli/releases/download/v3.0.12/railway-v3.0.12-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.tar.gz
npm ERR! Error: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
npm ERR!     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\warn-mixin.js:21:40)
npm ERR!     at Unpack.warn (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\unpack.js:229:18)
npm ERR!     at Unpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:83:14)
npm ERR!     at Unpack.emit (node:events:539:35)
npm ERR!     at Unpack.[emit] (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:303:12)
npm ERR!     at Unpack.[maybeEnd] (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:426:17)
npm ERR!     at Unpack.[consumeChunk] (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:458:21)
npm ERR!     at Unzip.<anonymous> (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:372:29)
npm ERR!     at Unzip.emit (node:events:539:35)
npm ERR!     at Unzip.[emitEnd2] (C:\Users\veget\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@railway\cli\node_modules\minizlib\node_modules\minipass\index.js:524:23) {
npm ERR!   recoverable: false,
npm ERR!   file: 'downloaded.tar.gz',
npm ERR!   cwd: 'C:/Users/veget/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@railway/cli/bin',
npm ERR!   code: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE',
npm ERR!   tarCode: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE'
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\veget\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-15T00_09_23_401Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: I am also having this exact issue. No issues with anything else but Railway CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I don't know what fixed it. I restarted my computer several times when trying before, and tried several times over a couple days. Walked away from it for a week and just tried now and it installed no problem.

Comment: It appears that Railway has a really unreliable CLI, not production ready as they claim.